# Responsive table not collapsing properly because of bootstrap css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying make my table responsive so that on mobile devices the appearance looks much nicer and drops to two rows but am running into issues because I have to use bootstraps css.

What I am trying to accomplish.
https://jsfiddle.net/5u3a2snh/8/

Unable to get it to work with bootstrap:
https://jsfiddle.net/5u3a2snh/9/

My full blown project that will not accept any of the changes because of bootstrap:
https://jsfiddle.net/vo1npqdx/320/

Will someone please help me get this to work with still using bootstraps css? I am unsure of why there css is affecting my table so much.

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped"> 
            <thead> 
                <tr> 
                    <th>Pay</th> 
                    <th>Print</th> 
                    <th>Year</th> 
                    <th>Property Id</th> 
                    <th>Name/Location</th> 
                    <th>Status</th> 
                    <th>Amount Paid</th> 
                    <th>Date Paid</th> 
                    <th>Due</th> 
                    <th>Pin</th> 
                    <th>Box</th>
                </tr> 
            </thead> 
            <tbody> 
                <tr>
                    <td scope="row"><button class="btn btn-info btn-xs">Pay Now</button></td> 
                    <td><button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Print Bill</button><br><button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Print Receipt</button></td> 
                    <td>2016</td> 
                    <td><a href="invoicepage.html">2609110008</a></td> 
                    <td>Table cell</td> 
                    <td>Paid</td> 
                    <td>1,372.37</td> 
                    <td>12/01/2016</td> 
                    <td>0.00</td> 
                    <td>Table cell</td>
                    <td>Table cell</td>
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td scope="row"><button class="btn btn-info btn-xs">Pay Now</button></td>  
                    <td><button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Print Bill</button><br><button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Print Receipt</button></td> 
                    <td>2015</td> 
                    <td><a href="invoicepage.html">2609110008</a></td>
                    <td>Table cell</td> 
                    <td>Paid</td>
                    <td>1,430.83</td> 
                    <td>02/22/2016</td> 
                    <td>0.00</td> 
                    <td>Table cell</td>
                    <td>Table cell</td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td scope="row"><button class="btn btn-info btn-xs">Pay Now</button></td>  
                    <td><button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Print Bill</button><br><button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Print Receipt</button></td> 
                    <td>2014</td> 
                    <td><a href="invoicepage.html">2609110008</a></td> 
                    <td>Table cell</td> 
                    <td>Paid</td> 
                    <td>1,407.88</td> 
                    <td>02/02/2015</td> 
                    <td>0.00</td> 
                    <td>Table cell</td>
                    <td>Table cell</td>
                </tr> 
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Added JS tag incase it can be fixed using that as well since its another language I am using for this project.

Comment: I did not find the table end tag in your posted code. Please check that first.

Comment: @masud_moni that wasnt the problem but thank you for noticing that. It was there on the final copy sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give your css more specific selectors so that your css is used on the elements you want rather then the bootstrap css. For example, I've updated your css class:

```
td { 
            /* Behave  like a "row" */
            border: none;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; 
            position: relative;
            padding-left: 50%; 
        }
```

To:

```
table.table-bordered tr td { 
            /* Behave  like a "row" */
            border: none;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; 
            position: relative;
            padding-left: 50%; 
        }
```

Which states that a `td` inside a `tr` inside a `table` with the css class `table-border` will use these styles rather then the less specific bootstrap styles.

Please see this fork of your fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/2tq9gy24/1/

Note: you should go through all your css and make it more specific where it is being over-written by bootstrap.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yy1chscw/2/  (0ne of your media queries was missing a closing bracket so your css wasn't getting rendered at all)

Comment: Yes, give the table a unique class or id and then use that as part of the selector. e.g. give the table a class of table-special and then use selector of table.table-special wherever you set a style that you only want applied to that table.